# Saving Firebase user UID to variable/state - good practice?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm wondering if it's an okay practice to set a `uid` variable `onAuthStateChanged()` and use this `uid` throughout my app to determine if a user is logged in or not.  This way I don't have to use `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` or have multiple `onAuthStateChanged()` methods throughout my code.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user)
    this.uid = user.uid;
  else
    this.uid = null
})
```

Even if a hacker changed this `uid` variable it still wouldn't give him access to a users database because of my rules, so is this an okay practice?

Now in my code I will check `this.uid` to see if a user is logged in and also use `this.uid` to retrieve user data.

I ask because I'm starting to use `auth().currentUser` a lot to check if a user is logged in and it would be much faster to just save the login status locally to `this.uid` when `onAuthStateChanged`, if it doesn't pose any security risks.  This just seems like common sense to me but I'm still new to Firebase and haven't seen this practice in the examples so I have to question it.

Comment: There's nothing secret in an auth UID.  It's common to store them wherever it's convenient, and you should have security rules set up for per-user storage when indexing by UID.

Comment: The UID of a user is not a shared secret, but an identifier for a user (similar to how your UID on Stack Overflow is 8180588). There is no concern in others knowing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret/37222341#37222341 Btw: I also expect little performance gain from caching the UID. After the initial call, the lookup should be pretty instantaneous.

Comment: I understand.  My concern was storing the UID in local memory as opposed to relying on the server side response when displaying user data.  A user could potentially alter his UID to another user's UID.  But I'm pretty sure my database rules would still protect from this.