# Firebase security rules - is Auth generated UID ought to be kept secret?

Tags: ios, mobile, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I've been reading Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules guides (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security), and I'm a bit confused with regards to should I keep the UID generated by the Firebase Auth (lets say if my App users use Facebook to authenticate themselves) secret? I have this kind of data structure:

- users

  - UID

    - Lots of nodes of personal data to be read/written by the given user 
       only.

So if some malicious hacker gets hold of some UIDs, will he be able to read/write the personal users' data? As far as I can see, if someone know the UID, he/she can setup a request and pretend to be authenticated as that user? Or am I missing something here?

Many thanks!

Comment: A user's UID is not a secret. It's just an identifier, similar to your ID 7276386 on Stack Overflow. Knowing your ID doesn't allow a user to impersonate you. See my longer explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret/37222341#37222341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the uid can be retrieved under auth.uid in the rules. This is server side. Take this rules for example:

```
   "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid", <--------------------------------
          "online": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
          },
```

The arrow indicates the line I mean. It does not matter if you got someone else his UID, because when you try to retrieve data with that rule, it will fail because there is a mismatch. The auth.uid is server side and as far as I know, is pretty good protected. He can change his own UID client side and try to retrieve data, but with security rules you can prevent data exchange.

**It is all about the rules you define**. When you define the rule at the arrow, you do not have to worry.