# Firebase Cloud Firestore Database Rules data access denied

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application communicating with cloud firestore to fetch users data according to its **uid** and its working fine with the current settings:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

however clearly that is not acceptable as its public and comes with a warning from firestore:

*Your security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify, or delete data in your database*

In the below image is my current database setup, the collection consists of the unique user **uid** hidden for users privacy... what i would like to accomplish with my Firestore Rules is to allow the uid to only access its own collection uid with read and write access

[image: Firestore Database Structure]
i tried the below Rules but it failed to access the data:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /database {
    match /{userId} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help in pointing me to the right way in writing the Rules! i read the firestore guide but it didn't help at all!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: fyi: UIDs are not a private concern. I.e. I can't do anything malicious with your account here on Stack Overflow, despite knowing that your ID here is 3022454. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want users to read/write documents in their collection, try this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // collection. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /{userId}/{userDocs} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

If you have nested data, and want users to access all their nested data, try:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // collection. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /{userId}/{userDocs=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Docs:

- [Rules and auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication)
- [Recursive wildcard syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data)

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly! i used the second option as i wanted the user to access all their nested data.