# How to change email id on Firebase Authentication of a particular user android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is how i am changing the email id of current user

```
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        user.updateEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            }
        });
```

It is working fine

**Now i want to change email id of another user(other then the current user)** i have the UID of that user

***is it possible ?***

Comment: I think you need to [link the different emails](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) by signing in with one credential and then linking to another.  I'm not certain about email->email.

Comment: thanks @JamesPoag , i used this link to link the accounts and here i want to change the email

Comment: If you're storing the email in your database, then it can be done without any security risk and no need for Firebase Admin SDK, but other than that @Frankvanpuffelen said it.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit no , i don't want to change in the database i want to change i n the authentication section .

Comment: Then when you update email you need to reauthenticate user

Comment: @Piyush then i will have new UID, and it will be difficult for me to connect the previous UID data to the new UID

Comment: Before mark negative vote to the question , please try to understand the question

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput I m not downvoting. But if you want to update email user without logged in that will be a security risk.

Comment: no @Piyushke i am saying this to all,

Comment: _is it possible_ ? By you. So here everyone gave their opinion. Specially Frank van Puffelen .. So @Shaifali Rajput would you like to update email of user on risk ?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the email address for a user that is currently not logged into Firebase Authentication can only be done through the Firebase Admin SDK. If this was possible in the Android SDK based on just the UID of the user, that would be a serious security risk (as [UIDs are not an authentication mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret)).

For an example of updating an email address through the admin SDK, see [updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).