# How should my own server verify a web client signed in with firebase?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Web client signs in successfully directly with firebase.
Now it wants to talk to my own nodejs (non-firebase) server.
How does my server verify the web-client is really signed in with firebase? Note: my server **doesn't** manage any user account passwords.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
Seems to use this flow:

For simplicity, let me call my good web client Bob.

Step 1: Bob needs to send password + email to my own (non-firebase) server. Now my server knows Bob is Bob, and gives Bob client-side a token "bob-token"

Step 2: Bob on client-side calls firebase `firebaseTokenFromFirebase = firebaseFunction.signInWithToken("bob-token")`

Step 3: Bob sends `firebaseToken` to my own server

Step 4: On my own server, I can make a verification request directly to firebase `bobReallySignedIntoFirebase = firebaseAdmin.verify(firebaseTokenFromFirebase)`. And if ok, now my server knows Bob really signed into Firebase.

But question: My server doesn't manage passwords at all. So my server cannot verify "Bob is Bob" in Step 1. Is there a way for my server to only rely on Firebase?

Ideally, Bob signs in directly with firebase, and receives an **asymmetrically** signed JWT (containing Bob's basic info) that can be independently verified by my own server (my server only needs the **public key**; firebase produces the JWT with the **private key**).

Comment: Exactly what I need: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to sign a specific user in to Firebase from the Admin SDKs, as the Admin SDK doesn't have the concept of a current user.

The idiomatic approach is to sign in your users in their client-side code with a Firebase SDK, and then pass the ID token to your server when you need to establish identity/authority. This is what most Firebase SDKs and services also do under the hood.

If you want to sign your users in on your server, you'll have to call the [Firebase Authentication REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).

Also see:

- [Firebase: How to generate access token from username and password on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788289/firebase-how-to-generate-access-token-from-username-and-password-on-the-server/58792053#58792053)
- [Firebase authentication for private server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244311/firebase-authentication-for-private-server)

Comment: Thanks, @Frank. Your suggestion is good. But I believe here is another idiomatic solution which serves my case even better: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web Essentially, the client-side still directly authenticates with firebase. My backend then asks my client-side to send this firebase token, and then my backend can independently verify the token is valid, and my backend never needs to witness (like forwarding) user passwords.

Comment: Ah yeah, if this is not about signing the user in to the server, but about verifying the authorization of a user that was already signed in on a client, then that'd indeed be the way to go.