# Updating firebase realtime via API with UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to update records in Firebase Realtime database using React Native via API.

During development I had Read/Write rules opened to everyone and used to update specific items using the following code

```
const response = await fetch(
        `https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/myTable/recordID/basic.json`,
        {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            field1: newValue1,
            field2: newValue2,
            field3: newValue3,
          }),
        }
      );
```

Now I have restricted the "write" rule to a specific user that I have created. Basically only this user (the admin) can write into firebase

```
".write": "auth.uid === <User UID>"
```

I've been trying to pass the authenticated user details at the end of the json like this

```
https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/myTable/recordID/basic.json?auth.uid === <User UID>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

The documentation shows options to add ID Token or Google OAuth2.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated

Comment: Hi Frank, apologies for the delay! I aborted the API method and went for a different approach which I used in the past. Logged in first using  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) then did the usual firebase.database().ref("...").update.

Answer (score 2):

A user's UID is not enough to authenticate them with, as that would be a huge security risk. UIDs are instead user **identifiers** that you can share to **identify** a user. For more on this see: [Firebase - Is auth.uid a shared secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret)

You'll need to pass in the ID token of the user to authenticate them, which you can get from using the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients), or from the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).