# how can i access Realtime database by uesr id

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Hello i 'm using http Flutter to get data from Firebase Realtime db

I want access data by using user id not token

I try this :

My Realtime db  rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
      }
  }
}
```

and url :

```
final url = 'https://firebaseio-demo.firebaseio.com/Questions/$id.json?user_id=$userId';
```

but its not work :(

Comment: "I want access data by using user id not token" That would be highly insecure, given that the UID of a user is merely an identifier for them and not any form of authentication. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes for the realtime database need to be defined on the place in the JSON where you run the query. Since you run a query on `/Question`, that's where you also need to define your index:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Questions": {
      ".indexOn": "user_id"
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [indexing your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to access all data, not only " Questions " :( the url its just example