# How to access my data field in Firebase Security Rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

## Security Rules

I am trying to grant permission based at a document field:

```
    match /users/{user}/{documents=**} {
            allow read, write: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
    }
```

## Firebase query

Here is how my query looks:

```js
query(collection(db, "users", match.params.uid, "promotors"));
```

## Error message

But I keep geting this message:

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not in any way checking the data in a field in the documents, so it will never meet this part of your rules: `resource.data.uid`.

Instead what you seem to have is a case where the document ID matches the UID of the user, which you can check with:

```
match /users/{user}/{documents=**} {
    allow read, write: if user == request.auth.uid
}
```

Also see the documentation on [content owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Comment: Hey Frank! In my use case I am passing a hashed uid in the query.  And, the real uid is in a field inside the document (also the document id is the hashed uid). I am going to update my question with that information.

Comment: There is no query in the code you shared. The `match.params.uid` you pass is interpreted as a document ID. I recommend first making it work with a non-hashed UID (keep in mind: [UID values are not secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret)] before moving on to more complex scenarios.

Comment: I got it working without the hashes. But once I added hashes I could not get it to work. But, I checked the llink that you sent and it seems that hashing the uid is useless