# Get Firebase user data using email address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Could I know how to get User data by Email registered to Firebase Auth?

Because I'm using Firebase auth to create users by `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` in the system from backend. In that method, I'm avoiding password encryption.

And In the future, If I need to update a user password from the backend I want user data. And I don't save uid in my MongoDB for security reasons.

I read so many articles that say use `getUserByEmail` I think this is deprecated.

How can I do this? Need help :)

Comment: "I don't save uid in my MongoDB for security reasons" You might want to read [Is auth.uid a shared secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. This means I can save my uid. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) doesn't say anything about `getUserByEmail` being deprecated.  It literally says:

> In some cases you will have a user's email instead of their uid. The Firebase Admin SDK supports looking up user information with an email:

So, you should just use what the documentation says.

Comment: But I'm getting following error.

`Property 'getUserByEmail' does not exist on type 'Auth'.`

Below is my import

`import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  updatePassword,
  fetchSignInMethodsForEmail,
  getAuth,
} from "firebase/auth";`

And the code

`getAuth()
    .getUserByEmail(email)
    .then((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    });`

Comment: That's a different problem than the one you've originally posted here.  Please post the new questions separately with your code and steps to reproduce.

Comment: I will point out that getUserByEmail is specific to the Firebase admin SDK and is not available in the web SDK, which you appear to be using (`firebase/auth`).  If you are writing backend code, you should always use the Admin SDK and not the web SDK.

Comment: Oh. Now I get it. Thanks for the help. Let me try again :)